# How to create a pop-up message box to display error message in .net c# web-applications

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

Does anyone know how can I create a pop-up message box in server side, so that it will display the error message in the pop-up message box when save process is failed?

Example:

```
   protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
           {
               //save process

               scope.Complete();
               Response.Redirect(url);
           }
       }
       catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
       {
          //pop-up message box to show error message
       }
       catch (ApplicationException ex)
       {
          //pop-up message box to show error message
       }
   }
```

How can I able to create a pop-up message box within the catch to pop-up the error message box to the user when the save process is failed?

Comment: You want the popup to appear on the server or the client?

Comment: @Kiranu - please tell me that was a trick question - you cannot get a message box to pop up on the server!

Comment: @slugster - I know... but it wasn't clear if what he wanted was something that was possible (a popup in the client) or impossible (a form created by a windows service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using either the `Page.RegisterStartupScript` or `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` methods.

Comment: Page.RegisterStartupScript is deprecated.

Comment: Hi Drew, a good way to get accepted answers is to elaborate on the concepts in the question and then provide a specific working example. Alternatives are always good as well. A complete answer is likely to generate more Stack Overflow points for you over time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + errorText + "');", true);
```

or

```
 Response.Write(
     @"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert('" + errorText + "')</SCRIPT>");
```

Comment: @Alex Aza; I applied the code you have giving before the try{}catch() .. it's doesn't seem any message box been pop-up

Comment: @Jin Yong - weird, I tested this on .NET 2, 3.5 and 4 - worked for me.

Comment: Maybe javascript is turned off from the browser. Try turning it on.

Comment: @Jin - I just realized, you cannot test it like this, you can't apply it before try catch because you redirect to run `Response.Redirect(url);` in a normal scenario, which redirects to another page. To test properly, add one my line and do return just after that line.

Comment: @Jin Yong - out of curiosity, what was the solution that worked for you? Did you use 'Page.RegisterStartupScript'?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
/// ---- ShowAlert --------------------------------
///     
/// <summary>
/// popup a message box at the client    
/// </summary>
/// <param name="page">A Page Object</param>
/// <param name="message">The Message to show</param>

public static void ShowAlert(Page page, String message)
{
    String Output;
    Output = String.Format("alert('{0}');",message);
    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "Key", Output, true);
}
```

Comment: How this is different from my answer? :)

Comment: @Alex - When I posted my answer, yours was not yet visible.

Comment: that's weird. Our answers are 15 minutes apart. So now when you see this, you can remove the duplicate answer, or change it to be different, right?

Answer (score 0):

While the alert() scripts mentioned are OK, they come across pretty amateurish. I would recommend two options.

1. Have a label on your page which is normally hidden  with font color red, and bold. Then just make it visible and set the text on error.
2. If you want a dialog behavior, use what everyone is showing you, but instead of popping up an alert, pick something nice from jQuery UI with a nice error icon and even a help link or something in the dialog. Here's an example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message

Of course, if you want your app to seem more reliable, don't show them any error. :)