# How to display a message box between the screen when user try to insert a new record/duplicate record in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a profile website in asp.net using c#. I have a contact page in which I have id, name, mobile, email, message textboxes and cancel, submit buttons. I want to show a message when user tries to insert a duplicate record, and I want to show a message when user inserted new record and the message should be display in between the page.

```
protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtId.Text != "" && txtName.Text != "" && txtMobile.Text != "" && txtEmail.Text != "" && txtMessage.Text!="")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Sp_Insert_ContactInfo";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtId.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobile.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", txtMessage.Text);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        int ctr = 0;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            ctr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "error!" + er.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ctr > 0)
            {
                clear_Textbox();
                //FillEmps();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is 'inbetween the page'?

Comment: What does `Sp_Insert_ContactInfo` do?

Comment: it is a insert stored procedure name and in between means i want to show a message box between the page but it is not mandatory for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that your question is just related to pop up a message after inserting a new record or while inserting a duplicate record, You can do something like this:

Method 1:

```
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Messagebox Pop up Alert!!!');</script>");
```

Method 2:

```
    lblResult.Text =
        "<script language='javascript'>" + Environment.NewLine +
        "window.alert('" + Message + "')</script>";
    Page.Controls.Add(lblMessageBox);
```

Also you can refer these posts:

[How to create a pop-up message box to display error message in .net c# web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092169/5588347)

[How to display an error message box in a web application asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651592/how-to-display-an-error-message-box-in-a-web-application-asp-net-c-sharp)